# Beveling with different adjecent faces

Tags: vertices, edges, bevel

I have a problem with the Bevel tool. I'm fairly new to Blender and don't know if I'm misunderstanding how the Tool works or just missing a point.

I have the following (simplest example) blend file : [image]

This Object was created by joining two objects of different materials (Dielectric (green) and Conductor (blue)). After setting those materials and joining the Objects i removed the doubled Vertices. The result is the provided .blend file.

On this prepared object i want to apply a beveling with Offset:0.2 , Segments: 4 and Profile:0.5 .

This is where i get confused. Applying the Bevel with above parameters works as expected every where **BUT** the Top Edges of the middle part (middle part refers to the 3 faces in x-z-plane adjacent to the top plane between the 2 cuboid like bars).

My question is now : Why does it not work ?

After a while i tried "subdividing" the top face like the, above referred to as x-z-plane faces, and it worked for the middle part.

From this i concluded that:

The Bevel tool only works for edges that exactly share 2 Vertices.

Reason: The 3 faces define their own vertices ON the already existing edge of the top face. In this way only the left and right face share one vertex with the top face. This does not fulfill the above condition and hence the beveling does not work.

Am I right with that Conclusion ?

Thanks for all help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've correctly understood your question, here is an answer. Actually you can't automatically create an edge loops (and therefore a bevel) through a ngon, because as it's a surface with more than 4 vertices, by definition it can't tell what other edge it is supposed to cut through.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which edge do you mean by "central edge" ? The "long" edge of the top face ?

Comment: you could delete the 2 parallel central edges, except if you need them later, but for your current shape they seem useless

Comment: Just to be sure : This supports my Hypothesis that the Bevel tool only works for edges which share exactly 2 vertices. Correct ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, as I said, you can't automatically create an edge loops (and therefore a bevel) through a ngon, because as it's a surface with more than 4 vertices, by definition it can't tell what other edge it is supposed to cut through.

Comment: I've added an explanation of what I meant, if it helps

Comment: Ok your explanations supports my Hypothesis. I additionally didn't know that the top face would be interpreted as n-gon since i created it as a simple quad. Furthermore the structure provided was created by a pythonscript which only creates quads so i didn't intend to use n-gons at all.