# Why can't I loop cut all the way around the object?

Tags: modeling

How to make a loop cuts all around the object? I can select just one side and I need them all at the same time.

[image]

Here is what I need.

[image]

Comment: maybe my answer here will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129731/beveling-with-different-adjecent-faces/129734?noredirect=1#comment223824_129734

Comment: read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33670/why-does-my-loop-subdivide-not-extend-around-the-whole-shape

Answer (score 1):

If the mesh already is triangulated you could use the Knife tool (K) in Cut Through (Z) and Angle Constraint (C) Mode when you are in a side orthographical view. This will let you add edges regardless of the topology.

But most of the time it's better to just un-triangulate it manually by Dissolve edge or with Tris to Quads (Alt-J) in the face menu (CTRL-F).

If you have ngons you can find them with the Select All by Trait/Faces by Sides and set the number of vertices to Grater than 4.

You will find it much easier to work with quads.